# Start-Sleep isn't working in Runbook powershell workflow

Tags: azure, powershell, sleep, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to use `Start-Sleep`/`Sleep` in Runbook of Azure Automation account. I noticed that the sleep command isn't taking any effect but it does locally. The further instructions continue execution as though there is no `Sleep`.  I tried `Wait-Event -Timeout` as well. I tried placing the commands in as well as out of `InlineScript` section.

What am I missing? Is it just me facing this issue?

The powershell workflow is of the form shown below:

```
workflow W{
    Disable-AzureRmTrafficManagerEndpoint..
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Stop-AzureWebsiteJob..
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Start-AzureWebsiteJob..
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Restart-AzureRmWebApp..
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Enable-AzureRmTrafficManagerEnpoint..
}
```

So, without the sleep the above instructions are getting executed. The endpoint gets disabled and enabled from traffic manager and then I see the other states of webjob stopping and starting. Sleep doesn't take effect.

Comment: Is this at the root of the workflow, or inside some other block? It would be much easier to help you troubleshoot it if you post a sample workflow that exhibits the issue

Comment: I have added an example of something similar to what I am doing. I'll try some big sleep duration at leisure with something like Print 1.. sleep for 1000 seconds... Print 2. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: How do you *know* there is no sleep happening? How do you *observe* this exactly? I seriously doubt there is any reason for sleep to be skipped, if this is your exact workflow code. If you look at the job output on the Azure Portal, keep in mind that this output is buffered, so all the logs may be displayed at once. If you could add logging statements with timestamps in between, this may help.

Comment: Thanks, Anatoli. I checked by logging timestamp that sleep works. The workflow has same set of instructions for two endpoints. I see in the portal that one endpoint gets disabled and enabled. Second endpoint gets disabled. And then the web job corresponding to first endpoint shows stopping or starting in azure portal. Not sure, probably due to some latencies somewhere. But you are right. Sleep is working as expected. This completes the purpose of this post. I'll do some further debugging to get more clarity. May be I can try printing webjob state in the runbook itself.

Answer (score -1):

Workflows are designed for concurrent execution of multiple statements in a non-blocking fashion - there's no guarantee the workflow engine will wait for the previous statement to return.

If you want to ensure multiple statements are executed synchronously in sequence, use a [`sequence` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_Sequence?view=powershell-5.1):

```
workflow myWorkFlow {
  sequence {
    Do-Something
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    Do-SomethingElse
  }
}
```

... or, unless you're using any workflow-specific features, use a regular PowerShell Runbook instead of a workflow.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. Not sure why has someone downvoted. I checked the [long description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_Sequence?view=powershell-5.1#long-description). It says `workflow activities run sequentially by default`. I confirmed the same by logging timestamps at appropriate places as per Anatoli's comment.